# getting file.properties from JFileChooser and using it on ResourceBundle

Tags: java, swing, file, resourcebundle

Currently I am building a Java Desktop Application where the user can load a file.properties through JFileChooser to set the language. However, it throws me an exception:  Can't find bundle for base name language.properties, locale pt_BR.

My file name is language.properties so I don't know what is wrong. I want to load the default language.properties file and not language_en.properties for example. Here is my code:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
URL[] urls = null;
try {
urls= new URL[]
{
selectedFile.toURI().toURL()
};
} catch (MalformedURLException e){// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    String fileName = selectedFile.getName();
    int pos = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (pos > 0) {
      fileName = fileName.substring(0, pos);
    }
    ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(fileName,Locale.getDefault(),loader);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it specifically says "Can't find bundle for base name **language.properties**", then code snippet that you posted here is not correct: you are calling `getBundle("language.properties")`, where you should call `getBundle("language")`, same as in snippet.

Comment: Also, it is unclear whether your chooser is expected to select file or folder. And what if selected file is not named "language.properties"?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: I see. `File.getName()` will not return valid bundle name, as I already said: it will return `language.properties`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I fixed it on the code now and updated the question again. It gets the file name without the extension. But still, same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the issue. I was setting the absolute path to the urls array but I should have set only the path.

Here is the right code:

```
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);


    if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        int pos2 = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(selectedFile.getName());
        String path = null;
        path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath().replace(selectedFile.getName(), "");
        File file = new File(path);
        URL[] urls = null;
        try {
            urls=new URL[]{
                    file.toURI().toURL()
                    };} 
        catch (MalformedURLException e){// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        String fileName = selectedFile.getName();
        int pos = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        if(pos > 0){
            fileName = fileName.substring(0,pos);
        }
        ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(fileName, Locale.getDefault(), loader);
        }
```

I will make further improvements. Thank you.